# Could Keras prefetch data like tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

In TensorFlow's Dataset API, we can use `dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=xxx)` to preload other batches' data while GPU is processing the current batch's data, therefore, I can make full use of GPU.

I'm going to use Keras, and wonder if `keras` has a similar API for me to make full use of GPU, instead of serial execution: read batch 0->process batch 0->read batch 1-> process batch 1-> ...

I briefly looked through the `keras` API and did not see a description of the prefetch.

Comment: have you find it?

Answer (score 7):

If you call `fit_generator` with `workers` > 1, use_`multiprocessing=True`, it will prefetch queue_size batches.

From docs: max_queue_size: Integer. Maximum size for the generator queue. If unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10.

Comment: This answer seems to be right according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986815/what-is-the-parameter-max-q-size-used-for-in-model-fit-generator

Comment: From tensorflow 2.2.0 onward, `fit` now has arguments for `workers` and `use_multiprocessing`. I think `fit_generator` is now legacy according to [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/) on pyimagesearch.